# Meaning of “typical”

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of typical in below sentence?

> A renko chart is a type of financial chart of Japanese origin used in technical analysis that measures and plots price changes. A renko chart consists of bricks, which proponents say more clearly show market trends and increase the signal-to-noise ratio compared to **typical** candlestick charts.

Comment: I (a BrE speaker) had never heard of a [candlestick chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) which also seems to be a term of Japanese origin. Perhaps 'typical' means 'more usual'.

Comment: @WeatherVane It probably has more to do with you not being involved in the financial services industry than being a BrE speaker.

Answer (score 1):

There is no special meaning or additional context for this word. It means exactly what the dictionary says it means:

> **typical** *adjective*: having the distinctive qualities of a particular type of person or thing: *a typical day* | *a typical example of 1930s art deco* | *typical symptoms*.

So a "typical candlestick chart" is a [candlestick chart](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candlestick_chart) that does not have any special features differentiating it from other candlestick charts.